# meaning of "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" and $( cd $( dirname "xxx" && pwd ) in bash script

Tags: bash

This is a part of a bash script.

```
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
source $DIR/framework.sh $@
```

Please someone explain what these two lines mean.. It looks like  it's going to the directory where ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} exists and assigning `pwd` result to DIR, but I can't first understand the syntax ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}. Is there variable array in bash? and the second one is why doesn't it just do

```
DIR=$( $( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" )
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line gives the *absolute* path to the script, rather than a *relative* path. A relative path would be something like `somedir/myscript.sh`, where you don't know exactly where `somedir` is. An absolute path would be something like `/home/seumasmac/somedir/myscript.sh`, where we know exactly where on the filesystem the script is.

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` contains the path used to call the script. So, it might return something like `somedir/myscript.sh`. It's similar to `$0`, the main difference being that it also works when a script is sourced rather than directly invoked.

If you did `dirname somedir/myscript.sh` it would just return `somedir`. So, instead the script does a `cd` into `somedir` and then it runs `pwd`. That gives the full absolute path to the directory.

The second line includes `framework.sh` from the same directory, using the `source` command.